# NodeJS MongoDB Query slow to execute

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the following query (with the NodeJS adapter) to locate missing indices in a collection.

```
findIndexGaps(collection, index, from, to, callback) {
    var aggregateOptions = [
        { $group: {_id: null, min: {$min: from}, max: {$max: to} } },
        { $addFields: {rangeIds: {$range: ['$min', '$max'] } } },
        { $lookup: {from: collection, localField: 'rangeIds', foreignField: index, as: 'entries'} },
        { $project: {_id: 0, missingIds: { $setDifference: ['$rangeIds', '$entries.'+index]}}}
    ];

    this.connection.collection(collection).aggregate(aggregateOptions, {allowDiskUse: true}).toArray(...);
}
```

I have have set a unique index `item_id` for the collection. When I use parameters `from = 0`, `to = 50`, and index = 'item_id', the query returns the correct result. However, it takes nearly 9 seconds to execute, which is unacceptable for a query that will return, at max, 50 results.

The collection I am querying is very large. It contains around 42 million entries at the time of writing, and is growing by around 10 million per month. I can work with small query ranges (like 50 used in the above example), but I would like these queries to be as efficient as possible.

What is causing this slowdown, and how can I optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it takes nearly 9 seconds to execute, which is unacceptable for a query that will return, at max, 50 results.

The performance of a query is not dependent on how many results are returned; it is dependent on the amount of work being performed to generate the results and the amount of resources available at the time the work is being performed.

Fully diagnosing performance will require a lot more information, but I suspect that the operation is slow because the $group stage is scanning all 42 million documents in your collection and aggregating results. Considering adding a preliminary [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage to filter out data that doesn't need to be aggregated.

You should also make sure the $lookup stage queries are indexed on both collections (e.g. indexing 'rangeIds' on the source collection and whatever the index field is on the foreign collection).

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the cause of the slowdown was because I wasn't including a `$match` operator before grouping, so it would load my entire data set, then group, then search for gaps.

Here's the option I used to solve the problem:

```
//In aggregateOptions[]:
{ $match: { [index]: { $lte: to, $gte: from } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with your platform support team or documentation—the optimum number of entries a collection can handle. This sounds like a Big Data case to me. Anything beyond a hundred thousand entries I'd think may not be supported by MongoDB — I'm guessing for that huge volume of a data you'll probably need more advanced database products that are faster.